# Turning rows from sql table into headers in Pentaho

Tags: pentaho, pentaho-spoon

I have a SQL table that return name and I would like to take that result and turn into headers (csv file)

for example: select name from TBL give me

name
Client Name
Phone Number
City

Is it possible to turn those return rows and convert into a header?   I have try to find something but had no luck.  The reason for this is to make the header dynamic.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: I agree that some more information might be needed, but so far as I can read now, it al looks like you might want to dive into metadata-injection to find your answer. Will help more, if more info is available